# The time.sleep() function sleeps forever

Tags: python

Hello I have a simple python script that is supposed to do something periodically. Here is the code for it:

```
def main():
    minutes = [15, 45] #Minutes to take action on
    while(True):
        if int(datetime.datetime.now().minute) in minutes:
            #Lots more code

        print("Before sleep")
        time.sleep(59) #Wait 59 seconds before checking action again
        print("After sleep")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If I let this code run, it works perfectly fine for the first 2-3 hours, as in it will print "Before sleep" and then 59 seconds later it will print "After sleep" and so on. However, after those first few hours it seems to get stuck on the time.sleep(59) line. And the reason why I know that it's freezing there is because it will print "Before sleep" in the terminal and then it will never print anything again. I saw a post saying that it could potentially be an issue with the QuickEdit mode in PowerShell, so I tried disabling that and it still has the same issue. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: You could try setting `flush=True` in your prints but I'm not very optimistic this will change much. You could write to a file instead of printing to exclude it's something with the shell like you're hitting a line/buffer maximum or so.

Comment: In general, please either back up "it could be this" claims with a link that has something substantial (some random forum where other people make wild guesses without a clear result is *not* substantial), or don't replicate wild guesses that have no substance.

Comment: It's funny because I thought the same thing. I tried writing out to a file instead of doing the print statements and still no luck.

Comment: @Tomalak Thats why it is a comment and not an answer. Suggestions for standard debugging are totally legitimate here. Also, we don't see a link of proof for your "stated as fact" claim "Quick Edit Mode is a feature of Windows console emulator". Make sure you hold self-proclaimed standards yourself first.

Comment: @Darkonaut I was not even referring to you, but the OP. :)

Comment: @Tomalak oops sorry ;D

Comment: Maybe don't shoot so fast next time. There is no aggression in my comment at all., I don't know where the aggression in your's comes from.

Comment: @Tomalak Interesting that you spot aggression in my comment. Seems like people generally don't like to be told what they are and are not allowed to do here from people who are not entitled to do so. I also don't spot any reason for nitpicking on OP's question here and he also seems to have understood this was pointing at me.

Comment: You know pretty well which aggression I am talking about, so let's not pretend we're a little stupid here, shall we. It's not my fault if you mistake stuff for an attack that a) wasn't even an attack and b) wasn't even directed at you, so settle down and spare me the "entitlement" speech.

Comment: The more interesting thing is this: When I said "Quick Edit Mode is a feature of Windows console emulator", I was talking about this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jk2cJ.png. You say this also exists on other systems? I'm genuinely curious, haven't seen that anywhere else.

Comment: @Tomalek So it's just rude if other people tell _you_ what to do? Let's make that clear, what I wrote is totally justified, I was just sorry for mistakenly intefering between you and the OP. There was no cause for you to instruct OP what assumptions he is allowed to formulate here and you didn't even stick to your advise yourself.  I didn't claim anything, you were the one asking to back claims with a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `while True` for such cases is a bad habit. You should use <s>cron</s> Task Scheduler instead.

Back to your code - if it works fine for few hours it means there's a bug in the `#Lots more code` part. There's no problem with the `time.sleep()` itself.

Comment: The OP is on Windows, so it would be "Task Scheduler" instead of "cron", otherwise I concur.

Comment: Then again, there's PowerShell for Linux now, too. The stronger hint is "Quick Edit Mode" which is a feature of the Windows console emulator.

Comment: Thanks again, TIL something new, as I'm not into Windows lately. Good catch on the OS - I've edited my answer to match the question.

Comment: Yeah perhaps I will try a task scheduler. Although, my method should still work even though it's not ideal. You could be right in that there is an issue in the "#lots more code" part, but if that's the case, why does it print the "Before sleep" and then freeze?